# How to write and read more than one word in C string

Tags: c, linux, string, fifo

I'm doing program and in this program i have two processes, server and client. Server have to read string from input and then write into FIFO file. Client have to read strings from FIFO file and then wrote into .txt file.
This are only function responsible for server and client. File FIFO and fork'ing is doing in main function.

```
void server(void)
{
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char string[100];

    while(1)
    {
        fp1 = fopen("FIFO1", "w");
        fprintf(stdout, "Type string: ");
        scanf("%s", string);
        fputs(string, fp1);
        fclose(fp1);

        sleep(1);
    }
}
void client(void)
{
    FILE *fp,*fp1;
    char string[100];
    while(1)
    {
        fp = fopen("FIFO1", "r");
        fgets(string, 100, fp);
        fclose(fp);
        fp1 = fopen("file.txt", "a");
        fprintf(fp1,"%d_file: I get: %s\n", getpid(), string);
        fclose(fp1);    
    }
}
```

And my problem is when i type a string like "stack overflow", when i have two word, in my `file.txt` i get to lines:

```
8965_file: I get: stack
8965_file: I get: overflow
```

Is there any way to write this in one line ? Like this:

```
8965_file: I get: stack overflow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of `scanf()` which stops reading when a white space occurs for the `"%s"` specifier, change it to `"%99[^\n]"` or use `fgets()` instead but keep in mind that `fgets()` will read the `'\n'` and `fputs()` will add one so you might end up with more lines than you want.

*Hint*: For an array use `fgets(string, sizeof(string), fp);` to make your code easier to maintain.

Comment: `puts()` adds the newline, `fputs()` does not.

Comment: I change "%s" to "%99[^\n]" and i got weird behavior because program write on screen multiple times, that i can't count, "Type string:" and in file it write multiple times '8965_file: I get: stack overflow'  and then ends :( any ideas why ?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `gets(string)` to get more than one word instead of using `scanf()`.

Reference Link : [www.keizerkong.com/c/c_string.html](http://www.keizerkong.com/c/c_string.html)

Comment: gets is dangerous because you do not specify the length of your buffer, so it can be overrun with too much input -- use `fgets()` instead

Comment: It works :)
I have warning that gets function is dangerous and should not be used. Here is why: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Comment: @John Hascall thanks :)
I changed scanf in server to fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin);